# Python selenium not displaying text

Tags: python, selenium

The problem I am having with my code is that the title is never printed or stored. When I run the chromium web driver separately, I can get the title of the element just fine. So I don't think there is a problem with the element itself.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options = options)
driver.get('https://carverlib.ent.sirsi.net/client/en_US/default/search/results?qf=ITYPE%09Material+Type%091%3AADULT-BOOK%09Adult+Book&av=0&isd=true')
for i in range(0,11):
    try:
        print("Clicking on element "+ str(i))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="detailLink{i}"]').click()
        print("Located element")
        print(driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="detail_biblio{i}"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]').text)
        WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(lambda x: x.execute_script("""return document.querySelectorAll('[title="Close"]')[0]"""))
        driver.execute_script("""document.querySelectorAll('[title="Close"]')[document.querySelectorAll('[title="Close"]').length - 1].click();""")
        print("Closed element")
    except:
        WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(lambda x: x.execute_script("""return document.querySelectorAll('[title="Close"]')[0]"""))
        driver.execute_script("""document.querySelectorAll('[title="Close"]')[document.querySelectorAll('[title="Close"]').length - 1].click();""")
```

Here is the output:

> Clicking on element 0                                                                                                   Located element                                                                                                         <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bae6dfbc7cafe80a0cd5b96a94e2c8c6", element="95101708-1180-46e4-bd86-1821455c2bbf")>                                                                                                  Clicking on element 1                                                                                                   Located element                                                                                                         <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bae6dfbc7cafe80a0cd5b96a94e2c8c6", element="95101708-1180-46e4-bd86-1821455c2bbf")>                                                                                                  Clicking on element 2                                                                                                   <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bae6dfbc7cafe80a0cd5b96a94e2c8c6", element="95101708-1180-46e4-bd86-1821455c2bbf")>                                                                                                  Clicking on element 3                                                                                                   Located element                                                                                                         <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bae6dfbc7cafe80a0cd5b96a94e2c8c6", element="95101708-1180-46e4-bd86-1821455c2bbf")>                                                                                                  Clicking on element 4                                                                                                   <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bae6dfbc7cafe80a0cd5b96a94e2c8c6", element="95101708-1180-46e4-bd86-1821455c2bbf")>                                                                                                  Clicking on element 5                                                                                                   Located element                                                                                                         <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bae6dfbc7cafe80a0cd5b96a94e2c8c6", element="95101708-1180-46e4-bd86-1821455c2bbf")>                                                                                                  Clicking on element 6                                                                                                   <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bae6dfbc7cafe80a0cd5b96a94e2c8c6", element="95101708-1180-46e4-bd86-1821455c2bbf")>                                                                                                  Clicking on element 7                                                                                                   Located element                                                                                                         <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bae6dfbc7cafe80a0cd5b96a94e2c8c6", element="95101708-1180-46e4-bd86-1821455c2bbf")>                                                                                                  Clicking on element 8                                                                                                   <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bae6dfbc7cafe80a0cd5b96a94e2c8c6", element="95101708-1180-46e4-bd86-1821455c2bbf")>                                                                                                  Clicking on element 9                                                                                                   Located element                                                                                                         <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bae6dfbc7cafe80a0cd5b96a94e2c8c6", element="95101708-1180-46e4-bd86-1821455c2bbf")>                                                                                                  Clicking on element 10                                                                                                  <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bae6dfbc7cafe80a0cd5b96a94e2c8c6", element="95101708-1180-46e4-bd86-1821455c2bbf")>                                                                                                  >>>

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a text from a visible element in Selenium. Wait for visibility of the element or get `textContent` using Javascript

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="detail_biblio{i}"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]'))).text
```